# How do I reply with a reply_markup message after the first one without having to create it a second time?

Tags: python, callback, telegram, telegram-bot, markup

G'day everyone, struggling telegram bot newbie here.
I'm using the telegram module for Python to essentially:

1. After receiving the /week command -> give back the msg "Monday"(as standard) and under a row of options: [mon, tue, wen, thu, fri]
2. If the user selects "tue" -> give back the msg "Tuesday" and under a row of options: [mon, tue, wen, thu, fri], and the same happens if he select other options (wen-> wen msg, thu-> thu msg, you get the idea).

The point is that I want those option to keep being consistent throughout the selection.

But to achieve that I've noticed that my code gets really bloated for a stupid reason:

```
def week_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
"""Keyboard variable gets initialized here"""
keyboard = [
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton("Mon", callback_data='0'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Tue", callback_data='1'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Wen", callback_data='2'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Thu", callback_data='3'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Fri", callback_data='4'),
    ],
]

reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
update.message.reply_text(daysList[0], reply_markup=reply_markup)


def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
"""Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
query = update.callback_query

"""And I have to recreate the same variable here to create the reply_markup again"""
keyboard = [
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton("Mon", callback_data='0'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Tue", callback_data='1'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Wen", callback_data='2'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Thu", callback_data='3'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Fri", callback_data='4'),
    ],
]

reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

query.edit_message_text(text=daysList[query.data], reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

I have to copy the whole process that gets me to the reply_markup, or I won't be able to update the msg with the same options!
Is there a way to avoid such repetition?

Msg Example:

(You have selected "tue")

TUESDAY!

| mon | tue | wen | thu | fri |

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better this way.

```
def days_b():
    keyboard = [
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton("Mon", callback_data='0'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Tue", callback_data='1'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Wen", callback_data='2'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Thu", callback_data='3'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Fri", callback_data='4'),
          ],
    ]    
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    return reply_markup
      
def week_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
     update.message.reply_text(daysList[0], reply_markup=days_b())

def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
     query = update.callback_query
     query.edit_message_text(text=daysList[query.data], reply_markup=days_b())
```

Comment: Yeah, estetically that'd be better, but I was searching for an improvement in terms of efficiency, like passing said reply_markup as a parameter (which to my knowledge is not possible) to avoid creating again, or get a reference to it or something, as for now I have resorted to making it global, which could be a safety hazard from what I've heard.